# How to send parameter from one function to another

Tags: javascript

How can I get **par** value from function func() and use it to attach to a_span element in another function `handlerFunction()`.
par is an ID. In `handlerFunction()`, I need to get `a_spanID`.

For example:

```
document.getElementById('a_span35')

function func(par) {
  XMLHttp.open("POST", "some.php");
  XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = handlerFunction();
  XMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  XMLHttp.send("post_name="+par);
}

function handlerFunction() {
  if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
    document.getElementById('a_span').innerHTML=XMLHttp.responseText;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to put `handlerFunction` *inside* `func`, so it closes over `par` (but I'll give you an alternative below):

```
function func(par) {
  XMLHttp.open("POST", "some.php");
  XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = handlerFunction;
  XMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  XMLHttp.send("post_name=" + par);

  function handlerFunction() {
    // You can use `par` here, even though `func` has already returned
    if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById('a_span').innerHTML = XMLHttp.responseText;
    }
  }

}
```

The `handlerFunction` is a *closure* over the context of the call to `func`. Don't worry about the term, [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

---

Also note that you had an error in that code which I've corrected above: You had

```
XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = handlerFunction();
```

...which **calls** `handlerFunction` immediately and assigns its return value to `onreadystatechange` (exactly the way `x = foo();` *calls* `foo` and assigns the return value to `x`). It should be:

```
XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = handlerFunction;
```

---

And I assume somewhere you're creating `XMLHttp` (and I would recommend creating a new one for each call to `func`, not reusing one).

---

The alternative:

You can keep `handlerFunction` separate by wrapping the call to it in another function, either manually:

```
function func(par) {
  XMLHttp.open("POST", "some.php");
  XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    handlerFunction(XMLHttp, par);
  };
  XMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  XMLHttp.send("post_name=" + par);
}

function handlerFunction(xhr, par) {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // use par
    document.getElementById('a_span').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  }
}
```

...or using ES5's `Function#bind`:

```
function func(par) {
  XMLHttp.open("POST", "some.php");
  XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = handlerFunction.bind(undefined, XMLHttp, par);
  XMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  XMLHttp.send("post_name=" + par);
}

function handlerFunction(xhr, par) {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // use par
    document.getElementById('a_span').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  }
}
```

You need to use a shim for `Function#bind` on browsers that don't have it natively. What `bind` does is return a function that, when called, calls the original with a given `this` value (the first argument) and the arguments to give it.

Comment: I'd pick this answer. It covers all you need to know about closures :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function func(par) {
XMLHttp.open("POST", "some.php");
XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
    document.getElementById('a_span').innerHTML=XMLHttp.responseText;
    }
};
XMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
XMLHttp.send("post_name="+par);

}
```